# Other Than Exchange Web Service [EWS] is there any other mechanism is present, to get conversation history of Lync users by using Lync SDK?

Tags: c#-4.0, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, lync-client-sdk, lync-server-2013

I am creating one sample application [.net technology] by using Lync Client SDK-2013. I want to save the conversation history of particular lync users, recently i come to know that through Exchange Web Service [EWS] we can track the conversation history. But i want to know is there any other mechanism or any other web service [Other than EWS] to keep track of the conversation history of Lync users???

Answer (score 0):

The conversation history is just held in a Mailbox Folder in Exchange so any of the Exchange Mailbox Access API that Exchange provides can be used eg EWS, MAPI, POP3, IMAP and ActiveSync. On Office365 the new REST api's can also be used

Comment: as i know EWS does not required outlook must be running in client computer, whether this scenario applies for MAPI,POP3,IMAP,ActiveSync?

Comment: Mapi requires Outlook to be installed but it doesn't need to be running to use it if you use a third party library like redemption. POP, IMAP you need a client library which there are many available, Active Sync requires a client and licence in theory to use.